# " Laravel Session Array " Printing a created session array in Laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I have **created a session array in laravel** using the code:

```
Session::put("backUrl", array($workout_id =>URL::previous()))   ;
  //or
Session::push("backUrl.$workout_id", URL::previous())   ;
```

Both works and it has been created successfully and I could see it in the debugger

```
'backUrl' => array(1) [
    '78' => string (36) "http://192.241.4.104/admin/view?cs=1"
]
```

now I am unable to print it, The code i have used is

```
echo Session::get("backUrl"[$workout_id]);
```

it shows a `syntax error, unexpected '['` error

And I have also used

```
echo Session::get("backUrl[$workout_id]");
```

nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several trials I have got what I wanted **a session array for back button URL** and thanks to @Steini for his valuable suggestions. I am posting this as it could be useful to someone...

At first I have changed using

```
Session::put("backUrl", array($workout_id =>URL::previous()))   ;
```

to

```
Session::put("backUrl.$workout_id", URL::previous())    ;
```

Saw the [Session::push tag in Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#session-usage) and tried luckly it worked. Because the first one deletes the existing session array and creates a new one.

And printing the Laravel session array is as simple as printing a session *with added suffix*

```
Session::get("sessionArrayName")['id']
   (i.e)
Session::get("backUrl")[$workout_id];
```

Thus got my session array printed and used it for my back button....

Answer (score 2):

Because you keyed your entire array under the session variable "backurl".

if you var_dump:

```
var_dump(Session::get("backUrl")):
```

I am pretty sure you get:

```
array(
    [2] => "http://previous-url"
)
```

So wether you go like this:

```
$lastUrl = Session::get("backUrl");
echo array_keys($lastUrl)[0]; //workout-ID
echo array_values($lastUrl)[0]; //Value
```

Or you save your two variables seperately:

```
Session::put("backUrl", URL::previous());
Session::put("lastWorkoutId", $workout_id);
```

And then read them individually:

```
Session::get("backUrl");
Session::get("lastWorkoutId");
```

Comment: i have a list of 100+ and still growing records so this will make me create **`2n' sessions (i.e) 200+** if accessed all the ecords

Comment: Session is per user. Therefore each user will have one `backUrl` and one `lastWorkoutId` data, attached to their session data; not *200* sessions as you said.

Comment: but he could view any list so i need to set several sessions, thats why i am trying to use an array

Comment: You did not state that in your question but then you have to read the contents of the session as I told you in my first sample, save the array in a PHP variable and modify the array, apply some changes to the array (add or remove entries) and then and then save it again in your session overwriting the data of your session-key. This way you can handle an associative array in a single session-variable.